# Cordova get own device BLE UUID or Mac

Tags: cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins, ibeacon

I have for days now tried to get the local BLE UUID of a device, does anyone know if this is possible. I want to save the UUID of a users device on a users profile.

I'm using this plugin https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central

Comment: The [advertising data](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#advertising-data) you receive from scanning should contain an id. Keep in mind that apple does not return the ID but an identifier that is different for each device you scan from

Comment: Thanks for you input - I want the ID of the device I use to scan for beacons - the phones own UUID - so that I can "scan" for this UUID from another device. Don't know if it make sense?

Comment: Makes sense, but I don't know the answer

Comment: What do you mean by BLE UUID?  Are you talking about the iBeacon Proximity UUID, a GATT service UUID or something else?  Your question is tagged with iBeacon, but the plug-in you mention cannot detect iBeacon on iOS.  Are you using iOS or only Android?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong plugin. Use [cordova-plugin-device](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/reference/cordova-plugin-device/) and use device.uuid , also this has nothing to do with BLE.